# How would I search a certain word after a character in java?

Tags: java, string, search, substring

So I am doing some cw, and I want to search a string for words after a hashtag, "#".

How would I go about this?
Say for example the string was 'Hello World #me'? how would i return the word "me"?

kind regards

Comment: I would recommend using a regex.

Comment: Please post your existing code, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Use a *regex* and prepare a `Matcher` to find hashtags iteratively as

```
String input = "Hello #World! #Me";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("#(\\S+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

***Output :***

```
World!
Me
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the String on basis of that character say

```
String []splittedString=inputString.split("#");
System.out.println(splittedString[1]);
```

So for Input String

```
Hello World #me'
```

Output

```
me
```

Comment: they only want the first word after # and not everything after hash !

Comment: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` if the input doesn't have any #hashtags.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
example.substring(example.indexOf("#") + 1);
```

Comment: This will return hashtag + the rest of string; for e.g. "#World! How are you?" for "Hello #World! How are you?"

Answer (score 0):

So then John, let me guess. You're a computer Science student at the university of Warwick. Here you go,

```
String s = "hello #yolo blaaa";
           if(s.contains("#")){
                    int hash = s.indexOf("#") - 1;
                    s = s.substring(hash);
                    int space = s.indexOf(' ');
                    s = s.substring(space);
           }
```

remove the -1 if you don't want to include the #

Comment: This could fail. The input may not contain any `#hashtags`.

Comment: Think again. What will `s.substring(space)` return?

Comment: The index of the first space found after the hashtag is stored in space, this creates a string from the hashtag to the end of the word.. I believe I know the coursework which he is doing and if thats the case then there is always a space after it so this assumption can be made for simplicity.

Comment: Okay, let's assume your assumption is correct. There are still two grave mistakes you're making. Should I spill the beans? I'd like if you're able to figure it out :)

Comment: Spill the beans, I see nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72426/discussion-between-kieran-lavelle-and-ravi-thapliyal).

Comment: This prints `" #yolo blaaa"` because there are two bugs. You need: (1) `int hash = s.indexOf("#");` (2) `s = s.substring(0, space);` This would still fail if the `#hashtag` comes at the end but I'm letting it go as you're assuming the input will have a space after for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Using regex:

```
// Matches a string of word characters preceded by a '#'
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=#)\\w*");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Hello World #me");
String hashtag = "";
if(m.find())
{
    hashtag = m.group(); //me
}
```

Comment: You can use `while` to collect all the hashtags. Also, using `\w+` would exclude just `#`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of doing it would be to Use [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) and then you should use overloaded [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,%20int)) with a [subString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int))

EG:

```
 String myString = originalString.substring(originalString.indexOf("#"),originalString.indexOf(" "),originalString.indexOf("#"));
```

> Please note that this can throw out of bounds error is the characters are not found. Read the java doc links to understand in detail as to what this is doing.